# Workaround for memory leak when using WriteableBitmap.AddDirtyRect()

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

There appears to be a memory leak with WriteableBitmaps when writing to the backbuffer directly and using the AddDirtyRect function multiple times within a single Lock/Unlock. The rectangles need to define different regions within the bitmap. The memory will then leak when you try to discard the WriteableBitmap.

You can recreate it by inserting the following code into a new WPF application. When the application starts, resize the window to create new WriteableBitmaps and watch the memory rise.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Image m = new Image();
        m.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        this.Content = m;

        this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bm = new WriteableBitmap((int)args.NewSize.Width, (int)args.NewSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

        bm.Lock();
        bm.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(1, 1, 1, 1));
        bm.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(2, 2, 1, 1));
        bm.Unlock();

        ((Image)this.Content).Source = bm;
    }
}
```

We need to be able to discard the bitmap so keeping the same one around and reusing it is not an option. We could also not write to the backbuffer directly and instead use WritableBitmap.WritePixels() but it's slower and speed is an issue.

UPDATE:
I've tested the WritePixels method and it leaks all the same. It may be an issue of calling too many writes too quickly in different regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've contacted Microsoft on this issue and it appears to be a problem with the underlying c++ library backing WPF. We haven't been given an promise of when (or if) a fix will come but it is still a bug as of .NET 4.5.1.

There are currently only two ways we have found to work around this problem and they are mutually exclusive. You can either:

#### Never dirty any subregion of the bitmap, only dirty the full bitmap

The problem with this method is performance. You can try to counteract this by making your bitmaps smaller but there likely many situations where this isn't possible.

#### Never discard your bitmap

If you're going to dirty multiple subsections of the bitmap then you must ensure it will never be garbage collected unless you're about to close the application. This comes with it's own host of problems as you have to make sure the bitmap is large enough the first time you create it. If users are allowed to resize the window then you'll have to make it fit the entire desktop, but even this is problematic as users can change their desktop resolution or add/remove monitors meaning you'll either have to leak memory or not have enough bitmap to cover the entire possible size of the window.

Hopefully Microsoft will release a fix for this in the future but for the mean time be very careful with WriteableBitmap as it's very prone to leaking memory.